# Leaflet - geoJSON integration (Creating buttons from GeoJSON)

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson

(Not for HW) Hi, I'm running the following code and cant figure out why my buttons won't create. Instead of where the buttons should be, there are snippets of code. I added a javascript function to create buttons for each feature in GeoJSON but it looks as if the button wont work properly. Any help would be great. My question refer to specifically the lines of code starting from var = geoJSONLayer new. The geoJSON layer exists within the same folder as the index HTML file. The markers show up but the buttons cannot be created. The following turf function will not work either.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>First Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-ajax-gh-pages/dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #header {
                height: 75px;
                background-color: honeydew;
            }
            #mapdiv {
                height: 850px;
                background-color: gainsboro;
            }
            #side_panel {
                height: 850px;
                background-color: powderblue;
            }
            #footer {
                height: 90px;
                background-color: wheat;
            }
            .attraction{
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                background-color: azure;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" class="col-md-12">
            <hl class="text center">Mexico City</hl>
        </div>
        <div id="side_panel" class="col-md-3">
            <hl class="text center">Attractions</hl>
            <button id="zoomToZocalo" class="form-control btn-primary">Zocalo</button>
            <button id="btnBuffer" class="form-control btn-warning">Buffer</button>
        </div>
        <div id="mapdiv" class="col-md-9"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="col-md-12">
            <h4 id="map_coords" class="text-center">Latitude: 19.4 longitude: -99.1 Zoom Level: 11</h4>
            <h4 class="text-center">&copy;2016 <a href="http://millermountain.com">Miller Mountain LLC</a></h4>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var mymap = L.map("mapdiv")
            mymap.setView([19.4, -99.1], 12);
            
            var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
            mymap.addLayer(backgroundLayer);
            
//          var zocaloMarker = L.marker([19.43278, -99.13333]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<h3 class='text-center '>Zocalo</h3><a href='https://momento360.com/e/u/f427867d9e6a456a98d614d7e9f5c1ab?utm_campaign=embed&utm_source=other&utm_medium=other&heading=78.71035983306334&pitch=-41.283278407523014&field-of-view=75' target='blank'><img src='https://marriott-hotels.marriott.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2019/08/Marriott_Logo.png' width='100px'></a>");
                        
            $("#zoomToZocalo").click(function(){
                mymap.setView([19.43278, -99.13333], 17);
            });
            
            var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('GeoJSON/attractions.geojson', {pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                var string = "<button id = 'zoomTo"+feature.properties.name.replace(/ /g, '');
                str += "' class='form-control btn btn-primary attraction'>";
                str += feature.properties.name+"</button>";
                $("#side_panel").append(str);
                
                $("zoomTo"+feature.properties.name.replace(/ /g, '')).click(function(e){
                    mymap.setView([latlng.lat, latlng.lng], 17);
                });
                
                var str = "<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4><hr>";
                str += "<a href='"+feature.properties.web+"' target='blank'>";
                str += "img src='img/"+feature.properties.image+"' width='200px'>";
                str += "</a>";
                return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(str); 
            }});
            
            geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
            
            var bufferLayer;
            $("#btnBuffer").click(function(){
                if ($("#btnBuffer").html()=='Buffer'){
                    var bufferedAttractions = turf.buffer(geojsonLayer.toGeoJSON(), 1, 'miles');
                    bufferLayer = L.geoJSON(bufferedAttractions).addTo(mymap);
                    $("#btnBuffer").html("Remove Buffer");
                } else {
                    mymap.removeLayer(bufferLayer);
                    $("#btnBuffer").html("Buffer");
                }
            });
            
            // 74-79 is a way to add an event handler to the map using a 'mousemove' event //----
            
            mymap.on('mousemove', function(e){var str = "Latitude:"+e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5)+" Longitude: "+e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5)+" Zoom Level: "+mymap.getZoom();
            $("#map_coords").html(str);           
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Src link to **leaflet.ajax.js** is broken.
You have to link it to a working link.

Replace this tag

```
<script src="leaflet-ajax-gh-pages/dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script src="https://calvinmetcalf.github.io/leaflet-ajax/dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I went ahead and changed the link out, for some reason its still not working for me.